# Financial Services TestClass Account Insertion

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am attempting to utilize Financial Services Cloud in Salesforce. One of the interesting quirks about it is that an Account insertion is immediately followed by a Contact insertion and both records share the same FinServ__IndividualId__c.

I am attempting to write a test class that requires testing this relationship, but I'm unable to insert a Contact record of type "Individual" and have a contact created through the managed package trigger and associated individual Ids. In fact, none of that happens. I just have an inserted account.

I have a commented-out section and that was another approach.

The result is Account:`{Name=234, Id=0013D00000OAwXNQA1, FinServ__IndividualType__c=Individual, RecordTypeId=0126A0000008xahQAA}`

```
Account a = new Account();
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.LastName='fname?';
    c.FirstName='lname';
    insert c;
    //a.RecordTypeId = [SELECT DeveloperName, Id, SobjectType 
                      //FROM RecordType 
                      //Where SobjectType='Account' 
                      //AND DeveloperName='IndustriesIndividual'][0].Id;
    a.RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Individual').getRecordTypeId();
    a.Name='234';
    a.FinServ__IndividualType__c ='Individual';
    a.FinServ__PrimaryContact__c=c.Id;
    insert a;
    a=[Select Name, Id, FinServ__IndividualId__c, FinServ__IndividualType__c, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Account Where Id=:a.Id];
    System.debug(a.RecordType.DeveloperName);
    System.debug(a);
```

Does anybody have any experience/suggestions with this?

I have attempted the following example: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCmQQAU
--with no success, including attempting the suggested work-arround.

Comment: why isn't your testmethod just inserting the Account and verifying that both Account+Contact are inserted?  I'll admit I know nothing about FS Cloud

Comment: Admittedly, there's a bit extra in there. The Client object shouldn't need to be defined at all, since inserting an account properly should create a Contact object, as well. The important part is: Account a = new Account();
*set some account stuff*
insert a;
System.debug(a);

At that point, it should have a FinServ_Individual_Id__c filled with numbers.

Comment: you might want to [edit] the question to focus on this fundamental issue. Is it possible you need to do the query on Account in the testmethod _after_ a `Test.stopTest()` statement as perhaps FS does its work asynchronously and those methods don't run until test.stopTest ?

Comment: @cropredy I wouldn't mind that in the form of an answer so that I can vote it "best." "asynchronous" was the solution!

Comment: glad this was the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear by experimentation of @calebKuester that Financial Services Cloud assigns the value `Account.FinServ__IndividualId__c` in an asynchronous operation.

As such, the Test class should be modified to look like:

```
....
Test.startTest();
insert a;
Test.stopTest(); // runs FS Cloud async methods
a=[Select Name, Id, FinServ__IndividualId__c, FinServ__IndividualType__c,
          RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Account Where Id=:a.Id];
System.assertNotEquals(null,a.FinServ__IndividualId__c,'FS IndiviualID sb assigned when Account is inserted');
.. more asserts
```

Comment: In addition, @future markup should be applied to a separate method created for the purpose of entering the record in question. The method must be called within the start/stopTest()

Comment: then I might not fully understand the root cause - I thought merely inserting an Account in FS Cloud caused the issue - why is a future method in the code-under-test required?

Answer (score 1):

cropredy pointed me in the right direction.

Solution is mostly here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wViIAI